# Google chart - get color for row

Tags: javascript, charts, pie-chart, google-visualization

I have a Pie chart with lots of elements.
I've left the color picking to google charts, but after the chart is drawn, I need to retrieve the color of each row.

I know that I could generate the colors array, and set it in the charts options, and that would solve my problem, I would be able to retrieve the colors from there. But I really don't want to create that big array by hand.

So is there a way to get the color for a given row?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Google pie charts, but I have a basic JavaScript suggestion for you. Maybe this helps. If you have a canvas image you could use a JavaScript pixel picking method something like the following I use for mine:

```
//get the image
var sampleImage = document.getElementById("checkimg");
//convert the image to canvas
function convertImageToCanvas(image) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    return canvas;
}
var canvas = convertImageToCanvas(sampleImage);
sampleImage.style.display = 'none';
//real position functions
function absleft(el) {
    return (el.offsetParent) ? el.offsetLeft+absleft(el.offsetParent) : el.offsetLeft;
}
function abstop(el) {
    return (el.offsetParent) ? el.offsetTop+abstop(el.offsetParent) : el.offsetTop;
}
canvas.onclick = function(event) {
    //get real position
    if (event.hasOwnProperty('offsetX')) {
        var x = event.offsetX;
        var y = event.offsetY;
    }
    else {
        var x = event.layerX - absleft(canvas);
        var y = event.layerY - abstop(canvas);
    }
    //get the pixel data
    var pixelData = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
}
document.getElementById("temp").appendChild(canvas);
```